# Notification not show next and previous button android 13

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I have started foreground Service which extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat class.
I have created a notification when Service run foreground but Service is only showing play/pause button. It's not showing previous or next button.
**I call or not call setAction function notification still ONLY show play/pause button on notification.**

```
private fun getNotification(isPlaying: Boolean = false): Notification? {
    val controller = mediaSession.controller
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "currentMediaItemIndex ${player.currentMediaItemIndex}")
    val audioData = listData?.get(player.currentMediaItemIndex) ?: return null
    val icon = getBitmapFromPath(audioData.path) ?: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        mContext.resources,
        R.drawable.music
    )
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
        setContentTitle(audioData.name)
        setContentText(audioData.author)
        setSubText(audioData.artist)
        setLargeIcon(icon)
        setSilent(true)
        setContentIntent(controller?.sessionActivity)
        setDeleteIntent(
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                this@MediaPlaybackService,
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
            )
        )
        setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music)
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(
            this@MediaPlaybackService,
            androidx.appcompat.R.color.material_blue_grey_800
        )
        setStyle(
            androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(sessionToken)
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                .setCancelButtonIntent(
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                        this@MediaPlaybackService,
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                    )
                )
        )
        //setAction(this@apply, isPlaying)
    }
    return builder.build()
}

private fun setAction(builder: NotificationCompat.Builder, isPlaying: Boolean) {
    builder.apply {
        val iconPlayPause = if (isPlaying)
            com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.R.drawable.exo_notification_pause else
            com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.R.drawable.exo_notification_play
        val actionPlayPause = NotificationCompat.Action(
            iconPlayPause, "Pause", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                this@MediaPlaybackService,
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
            )
        )
        val actionPrevious = NotificationCompat.Action(
            com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.R.drawable.exo_icon_previous,
            "Previous",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                this@MediaPlaybackService,
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
            )
        )
        val actionNext = NotificationCompat.Action(
            com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.R.drawable.exo_icon_next,
            "Previous",
            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                this@MediaPlaybackService,
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
            )
        )
        addAction(actionPrevious)
        addAction(actionPlayPause)
        addAction(actionNext)
    }
}
```